# How do we reliably get mouse and keyboard control in VirtualBox when using Ubuntu Linux after restoring from system state?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, virtualbox, virtual-machine

The host OS is Win 8 Pro. The guest OS is Ubuntu Linux. When the VM is booted fresh, there is mouse and keyboard control. However, if I save state and then restore from saved state, I have no mouse and keyboard control. I receive this message:

```
The virtual machine reports that the guest os does not support mouse pointer integration..."
```

I'm not new to linux. I've done all the obvious things. I've checked the video settings. I've reinstalled the guest additions. I even got tired, waited for the next Virtual Box update, installed that -- nope. :-)

Pressing the Host-Key (right ctrl in my case) doesn't help. Under preferences, Auto-Capture Keyboard is checked.

I have no mouse and keyboard control after restoring from saved state.

Any ideas? This seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

One way that I can think of that might fix the problem is,

Try Hibernate/suspend from the Ubuntu menu, wait until it completely done, then save state.

I'm pretty sure after this extra step, you mouse and keyboard control will be back.